# Python version? Returns below. Why? Fix?

Tags: python, installation, version

Played with Python a lot some time ago. Had a major crash on MacBook (thought all was corrected) but now, checking version gives me the output below.  Also, pip not working. 
Surely someone knows how or why this is the result on the version call.
And perhaps there's a pointer in the direction of how to clean up my system.

Thanks

```
d$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so", 2);
import _locale # dynamically loaded from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py
import _osx_support # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc
import encodings # directory /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /System/Library/Frameworks/P
```

Comment: What isn't correct?

Comment: `-v` means "verbose import logging", not "version".

Comment: You want `--version` or capital `-V`.

Answer (score 1):

[`--version`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-version) or capital [`-V`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-v) prints the version. Lowercase [`-v`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#id3) turns on verbose import logging. You want `--version` or `-V`.